# execlp hanging after execution

Tags: c++, fork, pid, webots

I'm calling an external binary ([Webots Simulator](https://www.cyberbotics.com/)) in my cpp program, by calling `fork()` and `execlp()`, that takes on an argument that is the path of a specific file. There are no issues when the path to the file is valid and the file exists, however, when I point it to an invalid file, I get the expected `Could not open file: 'file.wbt'` *but the child process does not exit*. I though it might be due to Webot's internal code and how it handles such errors, however, if I call `webots file.wbt` on the system's bash shell the same error gets thrown *but the process ends as it should*.

A compilable section of my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

int start_webots(const char* world){
    //starting webots as a child process with known PID
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
        printf("Starting Webots...");
        execlp("/usr/bin/webots","webots",world,NULL);
        printf("Finished executing Webots");
        exit(1);
    }
    else printf("Webots PID: %i\n", pid);
    return pid;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int pid=start_webots("/home/joao/Work/ASBG/code/cpp/darwin/worlds/darwin_cpgs_noise.webt");

    if (kill(pid,0)) printf("NO PROCESS RUNNING\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code lines after execlp are naturally never executed as long as the binary exists (webots is installed), since webots replaces the child process. However, after the error `Could not open (...)` I don't get any ouput to `stdout`, the program hangs, and I get the processs `webots` running in the background.

What exactly am I doing wrong/how can I find a workaround or solution?

Comment: Use `fprintf( stderr, ... )` instead of `printf(...)` to make sure your output isn't buffered. Have your process print out the PID of the child, and compare the PID you see with the `webots` process you see running after a failed `execlp()` call.

Comment: @AndrewHenle it's the same PID

Comment: Call `waitpid()` (or similar) to see if it just needs to be reaped.

Comment: Are you sure that Webots is quitting if an invalid world file is given as an option?